# Do Dynamic Subdomains Harm SEO or not?

Tags: apache, htaccess, subdomain

I am establishing a new website for just resumes, and I structured my htaccess as to provide dynamic subdomains as:

```
marketing.resumedomain.org/index.html
sales.resumedomain.org/index.html
california.resumedomain.org/index.html
```

etc. etc.

I did that because I think visitors can easily find related resumes, because it is easier to type.

But I have some concerns on SEO perspective because I will have probably thousands of dynamic subdomains (resume fields, regions etc. etc.) and I really wonder if google may think these as spam or not.

Any suggestions or thoughts about this?

Comment: Why not just stick with states and cities as the sub-domain similar to craigslist domain structure. How would you format a domain for marketing jobs in California?

Comment: I actually don't think to go through 2 level deep. If I do, I probably go with either marketing.resumes.org/california or other way. But marketing.resumes sounds more natural than resumes.org/marketing. That's why I'm thinking dynamic subdomains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question dynamic sub-domains do not cause your rankings to go down. So long as the sub-domain name isn't stuffed with keywords. In your case a single keyword is perfectly fine. You'll just want to be sure the content within that sub-domain is kept as relevant as possible.

Comment: thanks, that's a complete answer.
Since my goal does not fill url with keywords, I dont need to worry then.